Any thoughts why my questions don't receive significant activity? Any recommendations?
It sometimes hard to predict which questions will receive a lot of attention or will be answered quickly, or not. Perhaps three out of eight questions with low activity is a statistical fluke. Sometimes a question-writing style that works in one site appears foreign or off-beat in another site. 
But if there is anything I can do to spice these questions up, or adjust the wording, or change the style, I would appreciate the advice, thanks!

(deleted)
What is the underlying mechanism of scintillating scotoma? now answered/accepted
What would be areas of ethical or safety concerns with a smartphone app interacting with people sleeping?
Does the uncanny valley phenomenon apply to aural stimuli as well as visual? Addressed by research?


I looked at 3 of them, of which I spent serious time on two of them. Q2 has the disadvantage that it's anecdotal. Q1 is kind of broad. Q3 is dependent on the country and even institution (IRBs). Q4 is simply out of my comfort zone. But in all I think they are all 4 OK questions.  Note that they are reasonably well upvoted.

@AliceD thank you for taking a look! I'll give it a thought and many be try to refine. Certainly the anecdote can be extracted from Q2 with ease, I'll do that now. I also have to ask, is your comment about #4 (the uncanny valley being out of your comfort zone) a pun? ;-)

I like your questions a lot, and time-permitting, may answer a couple of them (#1 and #4 in particular).  This is a low activity site in general; I'm not sure that your questions are getting exceptionally low attention.

@ArnonWeinberg I've just renumbered the questions. I deleted #1 because of comments (now not visible) that I hand't done enough research. It's a valid complaint and I plan to do so, at least, it's on my list of things to do...
